# The very barest possible RESTful WCF service call with streams

Tags: wcf, iis, rest, stream

I want to make a web service with the following properties:

- It uses WCF and .NET 4.0
- It is hosted in IIS7
- It is RESTful

  - It's okay to keep the default output behaviour of collecting and handling WebFaultExceptions etc
- It has a single call that

  - eats naked HTTP POST of potentially huge binary files (should preferably not be kept in memory!)
  - accepts a Stream as an input
  - outputs a Stream
  - uses an UriTemplate for matching (there will be more calls soon)
  - wants the streams to be completely raw and **NOT** have IIS or WCF try to be smart by handling the content type in any way

The problem is that IIS and/or WCF keep interfering regarding the Content-Type, insisting on returning

```
415 Cannot process the message because the content type '...' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

no matter what the content type was. Can you spot any errors I have made below?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRenderService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/render", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream Render(Stream input);
}
```

With the following snippets from Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000000" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding
              name="FileStreamConfiguration"
              transferMode="Streamed"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000"
              maxBufferSize="500000000"
              openTimeout="00:25:00"
              closeTimeout="00:25:00"
              sendTimeout="00:25:00"
              receiveTimeout="00:25:00" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="RenderService" behaviorConfiguration="RenderServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RenderServer.IRenderService" bindingConfiguration="FileStreamConfiguration" behaviorConfiguration="RenderEndpointBehaviour" >
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RenderServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RenderEndpointBehaviour">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want to always get the raw contents of the HTTP POST body, and fetch headers from `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest` manually if I deem that necessary, and IIS/WCF should completely ignore all aspects of the request besides parsing it and sending it to my code. I'll use `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` to set aspects of the output as I see fit, also manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is so easy to do with the new WCF Web API library.  See http://wcf.codeplex.com  I have a sample on my blog which I will post once the power comes back on :-)

The interface looks like this,

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRenderService{

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/render")]
    HttpResponseMessage Render(HttpRequestMessage input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll look into it. However, it SEEMS to me that this should just work with plain WCF as per my suggested code and config in the question. I have definitely seen such usages in the past, and I suspect that there's just something wrong with the Web.config!

Comment: @Eldloppa  Yeah it is supposed to.  I have had no problem returning streams from WCF operations, but I always had problem sending streams.  I always hated WCF config files, so I never used them.  I always configured stuff via code.

Comment: Oh one more thing. If you know of a way to configure a service that's hosted _via IIS_ through code, feel free to share!

Comment: @Eldloppa  Sorry, I'm a self-hosting kind of guy :-)